# Foreign Key Relation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table, let's do it simple..:

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
    [DepartmentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
)
```

DepartmentId is the primary key of the table Department.

I have another table called DepartmentRelation:

```
CREATE TABLE DepartmentRelation(
    [DepartmentRelationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentDepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChildDepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL  
)
```

DepartmentRelationId is the primary key of the table DepartmentRelation.

Now I need to define two foreign keys, one for ParentDepartmentId and another for ChildDepartmentId each pointed to Department.DepartmentId.

My question is, should I add another foreign key between parent and child column as well? like for example define a fk from child to parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of hierarchical relation is usually done in one table, in your case on the `Department` table (you should think about calling it `Departments`, but that's just my preference). Anyway, a visual example of this diagram is the following:

[image]

Comment: Adding an intermediary lookup table generally adds a layer of confusion to the code, not to mention it tends to perform worse.

Comment: ok, but if I can't change the table now... with the FKs that I proposed before it's ok?

Comment: I don't recommend that you do that. You'll need to first insert every department that has no child on your `DepartmentRelation` as a parent, basically duplicating your data for no good reason.

Comment: Why I need to do that?, I just want to be sure that every parent or child inserted in DepartmentRelation, exists in Department table.

Comment: @tbag Yes, I was talking about the `should I add another foreign key between parent and child column as well?`, if you do that, then you'll need to do what I just told you

Comment: @tbag at least, not for this specific situation ;-)